# Import android project from IntelliJ to Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea

I have an IntelliJ android project with a different folder structure than the eclipse android projects. Can I import this project to eclipse without changing the project structure?

This is my IntelliJ project structure:

[image]

Comment: File-> Export to Eclipse isn't a solution?
It's look like default maven/gradle folder structure. Eclipse should support it.

Comment: Its not gradle/maven.Its an IntelliJ Project and has an .iml file. My question is that is ther any problem in importing an android project with this structure directly to eclipse? thanks in advance

Comment: So you are saying that your native android project does _not_ use gradle. I doubt that...  And yes, there is. If you simply try to open with eclipse, you will stand a chance of losing metadata from your build path. For me, my packages reverted to nested folders. I guess it just depends on how much the android framework needs those packages... and not just folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to build such projects which are not in default structure which eclipse supports.

**Import project** then Move to **Properties > java build path > source tab**....remove path to src....add path to java folder in the source code using add folder button... then build your project as usual

[image]